# What are the odds of restricting a web app for only modern web browsers?

Tags: web-applications, cross-browser, webbrowser-control, restriction

We are developing a web application, and one of or major concerns are about browser support. Develop a cross-browser application is expensive due to the time required for testing in legacy browsers (IE6-9).

Our interface is usable in all modern browsers: Firefox 3.6+, Chrome, Safari 3.1+ and Opera 10.6+. We are deeply considering throwing IE away in favor of Chrome Frame and advising the user to download a decent browser.

What are the odds of doing this, beside the obvious?

PS: It is a paid application for a restricted user base.

Comment: What do you think when you say 'beside the obvious'? What is 'obvious' to you in this case.

Comment: You need to decide the cost of not supporting those browsers, and how it effects your business.

Comment: i'd say this is an invalid question - quote: programming questions that can be answered, not just discussed. but, to answer your question, without more info, i can say its bad to leave users out. the solution is to have a low tech version with basic functionality, for those browsers that need it (this also helps in terms of accessibility). like google mail. cheers.

Comment: IE9 a legacy browser? That's interesting.

Comment: Dropping IE<9 support is cool. IE9 is a good browser though, I've been using it side by side with firefox/chrome as a dev and I have no complaints.

Comment: The obvious is to left behind the majority of users and to force them do download another browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll sometimes find that there is a large set of users with no choice as to which browser they use, so requiring or disallowing a specific browser could be a show-stopper.  Large corporations and government agencies tend to restrict their employees' access to their work computers, to the point where they can't install any new software without approval from the IT department.  Same thing with public computers in places like schools and libraries.  (And most people aren't likely to know about alternatives like [PortableApps](http://portableapps.com/), which would likely violate the spirit of the IT departments' policies anyway.)  As other people have said, it depends heavily on your target audience.

In some cases for paid applications, it's even risky to *recommend* a specific browser -- e.g. if you say "works best with Firefox" but a company's policy mandates IE, the reaction could be "we won't buy that for our employees, it won't work well in our environment."

I think there are two "decent" approaches to this problem.  The direct approach (perhaps what you call "obvious") is to put in extra effort to gracefully degrade your application's functionality in browsers that don't support what you're trying to do.  (And whenever possible, avoid using user-agent to decide what browser is hitting your application.)  A related approach is to rely on a client-side framework, such as jQuery, GWT, YUI, etc., to abstract away a lot of the browser-specific issues.

Answer (score 1):

For most applications asking a user to use a browser other than the one they are using is likely to annoy a lot of people.

I think you have to look at what your target audience is currently using.  If they are representative of the general public where IE represents around 50% of the market, you probably want to support IE (at least 7+).  On the other hand, if the audience skews heavily to other browsers you may be able to exclude IE.

You mention this is a paid user base.  Is an internal application for a corporation?  Maybe you could insist on a particular browser being installed in that situation.

Finally, building an application using progressive enhancements techniques can help alleviate some of the frustration with browser incompatibilities.